# Is there a way to make Visual Studio forget about C++

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am doing a C project and its so annoying that C++ keywords like `this` are blue and autocomplete always showing stuff from standard library and include autocomplete showing C++ standard library includes etc.

Comment: Any answer would likely depend greatly on which version of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 community

Comment: Coloring C++ keywords in C source is quite a good thing to avoid problems if the same code is later "reused". ;-) Anyway, Microsoft's support of C is known to be "_less optimal_" and VS might reflect this. I wonder if a solution is at all possible.